# Get all the Sitecore Form's saved data in code

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have a request that I need to use `Sitecron` to compile the form's data into single CSV file. How can I get access to all the form's saved data in code behind (not WFFM)? I'm using Sitecore 9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitecore Forms already have the functionality to export data.

You can use bellow class to export data:

```
  [ServicesController("Forms.ExportData")]
  [SitecoreAuthorize(Roles = "sitecore\\Forms Editor")]
  [SetFormMode]
  public class ExportDataController : ServicesApiController
  {
    private readonly IExportDataProvider _exportDataProvider;

    public ExportDataController(IExportDataProvider exportDataProvider)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) exportDataProvider, nameof (exportDataProvider));
      this._exportDataProvider = exportDataProvider;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("DefaultAction")]
    [ValidateModelState]
    public HttpResponseMessage ExportToCsv(
      [FromUri] ExportDataParameters exportDataParameters)
    {
      HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage1 = new HttpResponseMessage();
      HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage2;
      try
      {
        if (exportDataParameters == null)
        {
          httpResponseMessage1.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
          httpResponseMessage1.ReasonPhrase = Translate.Text("Invalid or missing parameters.");
        }
        else
        {
          ExportDataResult exportDataResult = this._exportDataProvider.Export(exportDataParameters.FormId, exportDataParameters.StartDate, exportDataParameters.EndDate);
          string str;
          if (exportDataResult == null)
          {
            httpResponseMessage1.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
            str = "nodata";
          }
          else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(exportDataResult.Content))
          {
            httpResponseMessage1.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
            httpResponseMessage1.ReasonPhrase = Translate.Text("The date range is invalid. Please select a date range that is within the range of the list.");
            str = "nodatainrange";
          }
          else
          {
            httpResponseMessage1.Content = (HttpContent) new StringContent(exportDataResult.Content);
            httpResponseMessage1.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            httpResponseMessage1.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
              FileName = exportDataResult.FileName
            };
            str = exportDataParameters.Token;
          }
          if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownloadToken" + exportDataParameters.Token, str));
        }
        httpResponseMessage2 = httpResponseMessage1;
        httpResponseMessage1 = (HttpResponseMessage) null;
      }
      finally
      {
        httpResponseMessage1?.Dispose();
      }
      return httpResponseMessage2;
    }
  }
```

If you want to use your own ExportDataProvider you need to register your own export provider like this one :

```
    <register serviceType="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data.IExportDataProvider, Sitecore.ExperienceForms" implementationType="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client.Data.CsvExportProvider, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client" />
```

Comment: Thank you @VladIobagiu for a very detail answear, this is what i need. But can you show me how to get a specific form and export it by name. Because i think sitecore only store the form's id in the database, so for example : export Form "A". Is there a collection of form i can get the id from or something like that ?

Comment: you need to get the form by path and then search by id in the form database

Comment: okay thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a report with Sitecore PowerShell Extensions, you can start with this:

```
$formId = "{FF4009B6-CA95-440E-884A-984496C65E32}"
$startDate = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-30)
$endDate = [datetime]::Now
$serviceType = [Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data.IExportDataProvider]
$service = [Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator]::ServiceProvider.GetService($serviceType) -as $serviceType
$exportedData = $service.Export($formId, $startDate.ToUniversalTime(), $endDate.ToUniversalTime())
$reportData = ConvertFrom-Csv -InputObject $exportedData.Content -Delimiter ';'
$reportData | Show-ListView
```

[image]