# How to access form data in sitecore 10?

Tags: sitecore-forms

I need to access the form data in sitecore. I have created a form in sitecore forms. Do we have to create a custom submit action for that? Or we have any other way also?[image: I have just created a form like this]

Comment: Hi Mahima, is this what you are looking for? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/25663/95

Comment: Yes, you need a custom save action. See related question.